# How to restrict a geopandas plot by coordinates?

Tags: python, geopandas

I created a simple `geopandas` map using a shape file from OpenStreetMap ([link](https://daten.berlin.de/datensaetze/openstreetmap-daten-f%C3%BCr-berlin)).

```
import geopandas as gpd

map_gdf = gpd.read_file('path_to_shapefile')
map_gdf.plot()
```

Out:

[image: Map of Berlin]

How can I restrict the plot to only a certain portion of the image, essentially zooming in on a certain location. Can I do this by specifying the extent of the portion of the map which I'd like to plot in latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `.plot()` method of `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` returns a Matplotlib `Axes` object. In other words, you can simply assign the returned map to an `Axes` object and then use [set_xlim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html) and [set_ylim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html) to control the bound values.

For example, let's use a sample dataset from geopandas

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read sample dataset
data = gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
gdf = gpd.read_file(data)

# create an Axes object and plot the map
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
gdf.plot(ax=ax)
```

The default map returned looks like the following:

[image]

You can use `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` to change the bounds.

```py
# create an Axes object and plot the map
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
gdf.plot(ax=ax)

ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(-50, 50)
```

This will produce the following map

[image]

---

If you want to dynamically change the bounds, each geometry object in `GeoDataFrame` has a [total_bounds](https://geopandas.org/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.total_bounds.html)
attribute. Assuming you want to concentrate on Australia,

```py
# create an Axes object and plot the map
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
gdf.plot(ax=ax)

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = gdf[gdf.name == 'Australia'].total_bounds
pad = 5  # add a padding around the geometry
ax.set_xlim(xmin-pad, xmax+pad)
ax.set_ylim(ymin-pad, ymax+pad)
```

This will get you

[image]